# Mostrar más de un valor en un select

Tags: sql, select

¿Existe alguna forma de mostrar más de un valor en una sub consulta?

Por ejemplo si se tiene algo como lo siguiente:

```
select cli.Nombre,
(SELECT TOP(3) DiasAtraso FROM Credito WHERE idCli = cli.idCli ORDER BY FechaDesembolso)
from Cliente cli INNER JOIN Credito cre ON cli.idCli = cre.idCli
```

Desearía mostrar los días de atraso de los últimos 3 registros de una tabla Credito, pero mostrandolo como columnas consecutivas.

He probado usando `Row_number()` e identificar por el indice, el problema es que lo tengo que hacer tres veces para cada columna, lo cual hace que existan más consultas.

Básicamente mi duda es como mostrar más de un valor en una sub consulta dentro de los campos de un `select`.

Comment: Al fina lo que quieres es mostrar el total de dias que un cliente debe, por que podrías sumarlos, o si lo que quieres es juntar el valor de varias columnas puedes concatenarlos y sacarlo como una columna, que crees?

Comment: Lo que quiero mostrar en las tres últimas columnas son los días de atraso de las tres últimas cuentas desembolsadas del cliente, por separado. La tabla Credito tiene un campo que hace referencia al número de días de atraso de el crédito que tenga. Basicamente sería:

Nombre | Atraso de la CTA1 | Atraso de la CTA2 | Atraso de la CTA3

Comment: Bueno, lo que pasa es que lo primero que estas dicendo en la consulta es que quieres crear una "COLUMNA" basada en un subquery entonces no tiene logica querer sacar mas de una, deberias de simplemente llamar las de mas columnas de la misma forma que estas llamando la primera.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Esto, entiendo es lo que buscas:

```
; WITH CTE AS (
    SELECT  idCli, 
        DiasAtraso,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY  idCli ORDER BY FechaDesembolso DESC) AS 'RN'
        FROM Credito 
)
SELECT  cli.Nombre,
    T1.DiasAtraso,
    T2.DiasAtraso,
    T3.DiasAtraso
    FROM Cliente CLI
    LEFT JOIN CTE T1
        ON T1.idCli = CLI.idCli
        AND T1.RN = 1
    LEFT JOIN CTE T2
        ON T2.idCli = CLI.idCli
        AND T2.RN = 2
    LEFT JOIN CTE T3
        ON T3.idCli = CLI.idCli
        AND T3.RN = 3
```

Detalle:

- Usamos una [CTE](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/with-common-table-expression-transact-sql) para construir la lista de clientes, ordenados por `FechaDesembolso` en orden descendente (primero aparecerán los más actuales)
- Generamos con `ROW_NUMBER()` por cada cliente un numerador.
- Lo último sería usar el [CTE](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/with-common-table-expression-transact-sql) en tres `LEFT JOIN` filtrando por el número de fila para quedarnos solo con los tres primeros.

Nota: Obviamente entenderás que no he podido probar esta consulta, por lo que eventualmente se me pudo escapar algún error, pero creo que la idea la puedes llegar a tener.

Comment: Gracias funciona bien, una duda me surge, acabo de aplicarlo con un bloque de select pero luego quiero usarlo con otro bloque de select pero no me reconocer el CTE, tengo que volver a declarar todo el CTE. ¿Existe una forma de reutilizar ese CTE? o estoy fallando en algo. Y ¿existe la posibilidad de pasar parámetros al CTE?

Comment: El CTE lo defines para una consulta en particular, si necesitas utilizar el mismo en distintos bloques, te sugiero que crees una tabla temporal y la llenes con los datos de dicha consulta, luego podrás reutilizarla las veces que lo necesites.

Comment: Gracias me funcionó.

Answer (score 0):

El operador `UNION` se utiliza para combinar el conjunto de resultados de dos o más instrucciones `SELECT`.

```
SELECT column_name(s) FROM table1
UNION
SELECT column_name(s) FROM table2;
```

espero y te ayude esta informacion.